# Executing fragment transactions after onPause()/onStop()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I have been reading [this great article](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) but unfortunately, in my code I can't make sure that I'm not executing these transactions on a callback.
That's why I'm wondering: is there any way to prevent the `IllegalStateException` perhaps by checking `Activity.isFinishing()` or any other method related to the `Activity` lifecycle?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the FragmentManager's state is saved with:

```
fragmentManager.isStateSaved()
```

If this is true, you can't run a fragment transaction anymore.

If it's not working, try to run `commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of `commit()`.

Comment: unfortunately, our app isn't still using support library v26, so we can't use `isStateSave()`. I ended up using `commitNowAllowingStateLoss()`